# React OnChange pass ID or Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to pass the id and value of a textfield to a function on onChange event.

I have tried a bunch of different things but i cant return the event from onChange because it only passes the value.

My function

```
    const handleFieldChange = (value: any, name: string) =>
    setFields({
        ...fields,
        [name]: value,
    });
```

And my textfield

```
<TextField id="test" label="Test" onChange={(event) => handleFieldChange(event, "test")} defaultValue="Test" />
```

Because the "event" only contains the value and not the actual event i have to pass the ID separately and i cant just do onChange={handleFieldChange}

This seems like a ugly solution because i have hundreds of TextFields

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your `event` only contains the value and not the actual event, the issue most likely relies within your TextField component. Most likely the onChange implementation returns `event.target.value` instead of just `event`.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the id prop of the text field without passing as 2nd argument

```
const handleFieldChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const {id: name, value} = event.currentTarget;
    setFields({
        ...fields,
        [name]: value,
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<TextField 
    id="test" // IMP! This is used in the handler 
    label="Test" 
    onChange={handleFieldChange} 
    defaultValue="Test" 
/>
```